# Devise raises error with Rails 4.2 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

When I run `rails s`:

```
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:455:in
`ensure in with_devise_exclusive_scope': undefined method `merge!' for
#<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x007f8743e19020> (NoMethodError)
```

When I run `rake db:reset` or `db:migrate` or  `db:setup`:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `merge!' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x007fca8d3f2780>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It seems like the issue was fixed with this PR https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3153 a while ago. Update the devise gem in your application (if possible).

Change the version of devise in your `Gemfile` to at least 3.4.0:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.0'   # or later
```

Then run:

```
bundle update devise
```

---

Update: Devise was updated to version `3.5.x` a while ago and `4.0` will be released soon (see all version on [RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise)). That said you may want to define at least a version `3.5.x` in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.0'
```

Or just load the newest version that is possible:

```
gem 'devise', '> 3.4'
```

follow by a `bundle update devise`

Answer (score 5):

recently updated https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3153#issuecomment-71185519

`Gemfile`

`gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Rails 4.2.1 .. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It was still producing the error for me with devise 3.4.1.

Removing `:confirmable` in the User model fixed the problem.