# Why won't my Rails Server start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to start my rails server tonight and it did not work. I'm very new to ROR. I'm getting the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/HighlandMcKenna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:414:in `ensure in with_devise_exclusive_scope': undefined method `merge!' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x007ff0d6ae3728> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/HighlandMcKenna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:414:in `with_devise_exclusive_scope'
    from /Users/HighlandMcKenna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:227:in `block (2 levels) in devise_for'
    from /Users/HighlandMcKenna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:330:in `block in devise_scope'
    from /Users/HighlandMcKenna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `block in constraints'
    from /Users/HighlandMcKenna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:816:in `scope'
    from /Users/HighlandMcKenna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `constraints'
```

It has worked every time until now and I don't know why. Please give me guidance.

Comment: Can you please update your question with your Gemfile? I'm thinking your devise version needs to be updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Devise raises error with Rails 4.2 upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611947/devise-raises-error-with-rails-4-2-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue I believe was fixed in versions 3.4.0

Try updating your gem file to

gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.0'

And then run

bundle update devise