# Rails upgrade to 4.2 Stack too deep error from arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, upgrade, rails-4-upgrade

I'm doing a rails upgrade and have been able to successfully get it to `4.1.16`

Now to make the jump to `4.2`... been able to successfully run `bundle update` but when I tried to run my specs, I'm getting a scanty `SystemStackError` as follow:

```
//home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:14:in `rescue in visit': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13:in `visit'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:241:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:240:in `each'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:240:in `each_with_index'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:240:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:210:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:209:in `each'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/arel-6.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:209:in `inject'
 ... 9265 levels...
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm trying to figure out what's needed to be changed/updated here, thanks.

P.S: Ruby version is 2.2.3

**#Update:**
I made a mistake in the previous stack-trace, was the wrong one, I've updated that now.

**#Update ( 03/16 ):**
This seems to be caused by devise...
I've managed to trace the error down to the following line in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
```

Comment: Do you have any `default_scope` defined? Do you use polymorphic associations?

Comment: Yes I do have `default_scope`s and polymorphic associations @spickermann

Comment: This discussion might be of interest: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19409

Comment: @spickermann I've tried commenting out the `self.default_scope` just to be certain. I also made a mistake in the previous error-trace I posted, updated that now.

Comment: Check for infinite loop.

Comment: Error seems to be caused by devise... I updated post with findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...

So, because I was trying to avoid [this issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3159) which also has [a stackoverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612295/4330954), it looks like I went too high with my devise version.

I was previously running devise `3.2.1`, and I took it up to `3.5.1`. I would have noticed this if I had only updated a single gem at a time...

However, version `3.4.1` works very well for me here now.

I should probably also mention that my `pg` gem version is `0.17.0`.